# Jquery not working?

Tags: jquery

EDIT: It was a jquery version conflict, thanks very much guys, is working flawlessly now!!

I guys,

i'm trying to hide a div using the jquery framework, i am calling the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#pagex').hide();
});
</script>
```

The pagex div is showing though...

The source code:

```
<div id="bigslider">

          <div id="slider-wrapper">
                      <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
  <img src="images/sliderman/iloja1.jpg" alt="" />
  <a href="http://iloja.pt"><img src="images/sliderman/iloja2.gif"/></a>
  <a href="capas-acessa-rios/cat_7.html"><img src="images/sliderman/iloja3.jpg" /></a>

              </div>
 </div> 


<div id="pagex">
  <div class="repassist">reparacao</div>  <a class="icon1" href="#teste">iphone2g</a>  <a class="icon2" href="#LinkURL">iphone3g</a>  <a class="icon3" href="#LinkURL">iphone3gs</a>  <a class="icon4" href="#LinkURL">iphone4</a>  <a class="icon5" href="#LinkURL">ipadwifi</a>  <a class="icon6" href="#LinkURL">ipad3g</a>  <a class="icon7" href="#LinkURL">ipad2wifi</a>  <a class="icon8" href="#LinkURL">ipad23g</a>
     </div>

     </div>     
</div>
```

Should be working, but i must warn that i am doing this inside cubecart cms/store, and the template is calling an older javascript.

Comment: Could we see the HTML for the div and body of the page as it may assist us?

Comment: Please share your html as well and the css too.

Comment: Putting together a jsFiddle is really helpful for debugging HTML + CSS + JavaScript issues.

Comment: are you getting errors in the error console

Comment: Just FYI, you can use $ instead of jQuery. It makes for shorter code.

Does the div have the id pagex, or the class pagex? Your selector is matching any element with the id pagex. Your code looks valid apart from possibly that.

Comment: Make sure you put the correct html markup on the page. Your code suggests you have an element with an id attribute pagex. Also make sure there is only one element with that id in your document.

Comment: The bit of code works flawlessly, but when i paste the code inside the cubecart template stops working. could it be because of a conflict between 2 different jquery called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works like a charm for me > http://jsfiddle.net/4mNrs/

Comment: Other than adding in the correct HTML to get this to work, how does this answer the question of why the OP's sample doesn't work?

Comment: The code he wrote is correct. Sometimes just isolating your code (like in jsfiddle) helps pinpointing the issue. It seems from his question that the issue lies somewhere else. In which case, jsFiddle is always a good start to track it.

Comment: The bit of code works flawlessly, thank you for the link, didn't knew about this fiddle. But when i paste the code inside the cubecart template stops working. could it be because of a conflict between 2 different jquery versions being called?

Comment: Have you added another jQuery resource somewhere in your application? In my jsFiddle example, I am using exactly the same jQuery resource, you are.

Comment: @Souza, are you script srcing to 2 different jquery versions? if you are... you're just overwriting the first w/ the last... if you 'need' 2 different versions... you can do a var `$j2=jQuery.noConflict();` and then the rest of the calls using the second jquery lib would be $j2(<selector>)... etc...